# How can I get red value from rgb value : android

Tags: android

```
  import java.io.File;


public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    TextView colorRGB;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton); 
   txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


//j*******************************************************************************       
    bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/folder/tes.jpg");
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

//j*******************************************************************************       

    testButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(400, 200);

            int Red1 = Color.red(touchedRGB);




            txtData.setText(Integer.toHexString(Red1));

            txtData.setTextColor(Red1);

        }});

}
```

}
i have edited the post and added the necessary code in order to make it more clear. Please find the updated one and provide me suggestions to solve it.

Sorry this post got deleted by mistake. am not able to retrieve the red value from the image. i tried this code. This code is an updated one from the suggestions i got .

Comment: It's helpful to know what problem you're having in order to solve it. Are you getting an error? What value are you seeing? What value are you expecting? Are you sure the pixel at 300, 200 has any red in it?

Comment: i am trying to decode red value from the rgb value that i have decoded and am not getting any error...but when i click the button the txtdata is empty... and yes its an rgb image that have red color

Comment: What do you see in LogCat if before you use setText you send the value to the debug stream? e.g. something like `Log.d("OnClick", "Colour value is: " + Red1");` Without some debugging it's going to be hard to work out where your problem is. (Consider: At the moment, we don't even know if your code is being called at all, because not running it makes no difference to the output if txtData start off empty.)

Comment: i have updated my code please view it and let me know the suggestions

Comment: yes it do. i am just checking whether i can get red or not. if so den i will remove the hard coded one. so for time being i just took one pixel.i am getting the rgb value of this pixel so i think red can also be decoded...but when i run the program its showing empty space in the txtdata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int Red1 = Color.red(touchedRGB);

txtData.setTextColor(Red1);
```

The red component of a pixel is not a color you can set using `setTextColor()` which expects an ARGB value. So interpreting a R value as ARGB will make the red component value the blue component value, with zero alpha i.e. completely transparent and therefore not visible.

Comment: oh yes.....u r so rightttt....i just commanded that line  and i was able to see the valu...thank you so much........

Answer (score 0):

```
int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
```

Should be enough

Comment: So check manually color value in Gimp for this bitmap, maybe there is error in other place

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to ask that you are having your color value (in RGB format) and from that you want to retrieve R value then you can get it in this way,

```
int r = (your_color_value >> 16) & 0xFF;
```

Similarly to get G and B values,

```
int g = (your_color_value >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (your_color_value >> 0) & 0xFF;
```