# image with only red value : Android

Tags: android, image-processing

Can we display an image with only its red value. Its just to see the different concentration of red value on the image. Any help will be appreciable.

```
testButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            int redValue = Color.red(bitmap.getPixel(400, 200));
            txtData.setText(Integer.toHexString(redValue));
            txtData.setTextColor(redValue);
        }
 });
```

This is a sample code. Here i get the red value also. But the last line is not executed since the red value is not a color...hence fully transparent. But is there any way so that
 we can manipulate this value and we can see this value in red color

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get red value from rgb value : android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326784/how-can-i-get-red-value-from-rgb-value-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like

```
   txtData.setTextColor(Color.argb(0xFF,redValue,0,0));
```

try this...

```
public static Bitmap getRedComponentBitmap(Bitmap source) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(),source.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    for (int i = 0; i < source.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < source.getHeight(); j++) {
            int pixel = source.getPixel(i, j);
            // get red color value
            int red = Color.red(pixel);
            int color = Color.argb(0xFF, red, 0, 0);
            bitmap.setPixel(i, j, color);
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

and I recommend to use this method in non UI Thread.

Comment: txtData.setTextColor(Color.argb(0xFF,redValue,0,0));                     on using this line am getting the same result...the red value is displayed but invisble..

Comment: @user3040168 post value of **redValue** here

Comment: its in hexvalue...bd.. which in decimal returns 189

Comment: then txtData.setTextColor(Color.argb(0xFF,0xBD,0,0)) is working for me. the text is visible

Comment: yes its visible...it worked it was my mistake one line got commanded by mistake.....but will you please tell me why this transparency went off...is it because we provided the alpha value....

Comment: yes. because of only alpha value. red color component will not have alpha value. and we are setting alpha using Color.argb(....);

Answer (score 0):

[BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) class probably has all the methods you need to achieve what you want.

1. Load the image in to buffer
2. Loop through the image pixel by pixel with two for loops for x and y
3. Use getRGB to get the value of that pixel
4. Modify the RGB value by shifting the result from step 3, I think right shift the value 16 and then left shift again 16 should work.
5. use setRGB to put the value back into that particular pixel

Comment: is there any code example